# Why my deltarune 2 didn't continue my deltarune 1 progress?

Tags: deltarune

In chapter 1, I have a few items and armor that can unlock a dialog on chapter 2, but for some reason, when I start to play on chapter 2, it didn't continue my chapter 1 progress. It's all back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just need to use my chapter 1 save file to continue the progress.